# How to trim last 10 letters from each string element stored in an array in php

Tags: php

Please any one help me. As I am a noobe in PHP coding. Is there any built in function to trim letters in PHP??

Comment: Next time start with reading the manual, please.

Comment: Consider whether you literally mean letters or whether characters will do.

Comment: Search on google before asking [trim](http://pk1.php.net/trim)

Comment: Er, it's totally not trim. That removes whitespace.

Comment: `trim` will not work, try `substr`

Comment: Yeah I did googled this question... Nd If I would have found the answer I wouldn't have asked this question here

Comment: It's hard to believe you googled, look at [this search](https://www.google.hu/search?q=php+string+last+10+characters). Looks like some good starting point...

Comment: `array_walk($myArray, function(&$value) { $value = substr($value, 0, -10)); });`

Comment: @Paul: you can trim any character you like using `trim` - the second parameter takes a string of characters to remove from the ends. It wouldn't be suitable here though, as the OP wishes to remove a specific number of characters.

Comment: To be fair, if you Google for "trim last 10 letters php" you don't get the right answers.

Comment: And theres also [rtrim](http://pk1.php.net/rtrim) and [ltrim](http://pk1.php.net/manual/en/function.ltrim.php) available for you :)

Comment: @PaulGregory Well, trying one search and giving up does not really show "research effort".

Comment: for what it's worth i searched 'trim letters from string php' and the first link was PHP substr. while we are happy to help out, it seems SO has become the first option for many people, rather than a couple minutes of solid searching.

Comment: @halfer True, my definition of PHP's trim is a simplification. But the point is that the OP's use of the word trim is wildly different to PHP's. Several people suggested he just use trim() tho some comments have been deleted.

Comment: @AndrewBrown There will always be someone who answers these useless questions, because it is easy rep. So you cannot really get rid of these vampire-like people...

Comment: @user3216422 To echo the top comment, whilst it's unrealistic to read the whole PHP manual, it is very worthwhile reading through all the string functions in PHP: http://us2.php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php and getting your head round the terminology used with strings so you can search better in future. It's not entirely logical and sometimes you may need to think of an opposite way of doing something - eg retaining all but 10 characters, rather than losing 10.

Comment: @kapa There really needs to be a way to divide "my problem is with my ability to find the right search terms to describe what I'm trying to achieve" from "my problem is with PHP".

Comment: @kapa and in this case i took the easy points

Comment: @AndrewBrown I would lie if I said I never did before.

Answer (score 4):

Lookup `substr()`

https://www.php.net/substr

Should do the trick

```
$var = 'teststring1234567890';

substr($var, 0, -10);
```

returns 'teststring'